# JSPC task giving error

Tags: ant

apache.jasper.JasperException [jasperc] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unrecognized option: -v9.  Use -help for help. for a simple build.xml

```
<property name="message" value="Deploying the .jar file." />
<property name="src" location="source" />
<property name="output" location="bin" />

<target name="main" depends="init, compile">
    <echo>
        ${message}
    </echo>
</target>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${output}" />
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <jspc srcdir="${src}"
        destdir="${output}"
        package="org.antbook.jsp"
        verbose="9">
        <include name="**/*.jsp" />
    </jspc>
</target>
```

in the lib of ant
I put
servlet-api-2.4.jar
jasper-compiler.jar
jasper-runtime.jar

I don t know what append

Comment: Try to remove the `verbose="9"` from the jspc tag.

Comment: removing this option from ant task descriptor sets its value to 0, causing error: Unrecognized option: -v0. Use -help for help. for a simple build.xml

Answer (score 0):

It looks like -v option has been removed from jasper compiler 5.5.
Using jasper compiler 4.1 worked for me just fine.